# Sliding Tab layout not working in Pre - Lollipop Devices but working fine in Lollipop Devices

Tags: android, tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using SlidingTabLayout,its working fine in Lollipop devices but when I m trying to run in pre-lollipop devices its showing an error

"android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView"

But I have made another Project having same codes, in that SlidingTabLayout is working fine in both lollipop and pre-lollipop devices.

I m not getting whats the prob, same code but not working.
Please help me.

This is the XML layout code of the custom layout for the Tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/tabContainer"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:padding="8dp"
       android:background="@drawable/tab_bg"
       android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tabImage"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabText"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you provide your layout xml file?

Comment: I have added the xml layout code , @Arkadiy

Comment: Add also code where error occurs..